# Neasted Table in Angulars Mean Stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

i am using angularjs and i am work on nested table functionality in angularjs i have example here i attached the link also.i  my case  i am doing nested table when i expand first row  some relevant div content will open and at the same time i expand the second row means first row must be be closed.

anyone help how to solve this problem

Thanks

```
plnkr.co/edit/yYq1dt?p=preview
```

Comment: I have updated the plunker with some changes fixing all the errors, tell me the scenario that you need help on. Check this plunker code https://plnkr.co/edit/gjALbGRt2MAEgDwU8r2D?p=preview

Comment: not like that here directly + and - button show .my need is when i expand first one its give some data it's work correctly but without close the first one now i open second row means first row must be hide here it's not hide @Pramod_Para first row means that hidden content will hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way do to that is call function after click on plus button which hide all expanded person details.

```
<button ng-if="!person.expanded" ng-click="showPersonDetails(person);person.expanded = true">+</button>
```

Here working example -> http://plnkr.co/edit/TrJpm7FnyClJS662qLgU?p=preview

Comment: Hmm, now i look at this code and i think this function should has another name, for example. `hideCurrentExpandedPersonDetails` and `person` param is unnecessary so you can remove it :)